# How to add a condition for INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

Every month I run a procedure that creates a table with data for the previous month (#prev_month).
After that, the data is added to the table where the history for all months is stored.
How to make that if the procedure was run 2 times a month, the data is added to the history table only once.

```
select month, count (UserID) as Number
into #prev_month
from Compliance
where StatusID=17
and LastRequestDate>dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate()-1)-1,0)  
group by Month


insert into History_tbl
select * from #prev_month
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What is `month`?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can use `not exists`:

```
insert into history (month, number)
    select month, number
    from #prev_month
    where not exists (select 1
                      from history h2
                      where month = XXX
                     );
```

It is unclear what `month` is.  And XXX depends on that.  It might be something like `datediff(month, month, getdate()) = 1`, if `month` is a `date`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will use this

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
insert into History_tbl (month, Number)

select month, count (UserID) as Number

from Compliance
where StatusID=17
and LastRequestDate>dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate()-1)-1,0)  
group by Month
```

Comment: in this case if i run procedure twice it insert into History_tbl 2 rows, i need only 1 per month

Answer (score 0):

I would use NOT EXISTS with a correlated subquery

```
insert history([month], number)
select *
from #prev_month pv
where not exists (select 1
                  from history h
                  where h.[month]=pv.[month]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also think of MERGE statement, which will ensure that only one data exists for the month, irrespective of how many times, the statement is executed.

```sql
MERGE into History_tbl AS tgt
USING (select * from #prev_month) AS src
ON tgt.Month = src.Month
WHEN MATCHED THEN
tgt.number = src.number
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (Month, number)
VALUES (src.Month, src.number);
```